# Github Actions: Report dotnet test result as annotations

Tags: .net, .net-core, continuous-integration, github-actions, dotnet-test

If you run tests using Azure Pipelines you would get some cool results on the checks tabs.

[image]

Is there any way to do the same from Github Actions so we don't have to go through the console output?

[image]

Answer (score 8):

Here is one solution:
https://github.com/microsoft/vstest/issues/2370#issuecomment-602233131

GitHub user Tyrrrz made a small proof of concept using GitHub Actions commands. This reports test failures to the GH Actions platform, letting you see them in the Annotations view and navigate to the exact/file that triggered it. This is not exactly the solution to "support colorized output" but may solve the underlying issue that GitHub Actions doesn't show the list of failed tests nicely.

https://github.com/Tyrrrz/GitHubActionsTestLogger
https://github.com/Tyrrrz/GitHubActionsTestLogger/runs/525594126?check_suite_focus=true

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [Test Reporter](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/test-reporter) action which provides a nice test report summary.

It supports many languages / frameworks:

> .NET / xUnit / NUnit / MSTest
> Dart / test
> Flutter / test
> Java / JUnit
> JavaScript / JEST / Mocha

Here's what a report looks like (screenshot from the Test Reporter project):
[image: Test results sample]

Comment: This is a good solution for internal projects but for public projects with many external PRs it is not practical. It fails by default for external PRs and the workaround described in the docs requires another workflow action to run (it didn't work for us anyway).

Comment: This has been recently implemented in the Testcontainers repository. You can look at [cicd.yml](https://github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-dotnet/blob/d7b4f14473abfbf4ec6cb717a7d03d78224c3d6b/.github/workflows/cicd.yml#L81-L88) and [test-report.yml](https://github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-dotnet/blob/d7b4f14473abfbf4ec6cb717a7d03d78224c3d6b/.github/workflows/test-report.yml) to see how it works.